# list.sort(reverse = True) not changing the list to descending order

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I am doing a question on extracting a number from a string. It states that:

There are various numbers in each test case you need to find the number in each test case. Each test case has various numbers in sequence. You need to find only those numbers which do not contain 9. For eg, if the string contains "hello this is alpha 5051 and 9475".You will extract 5051 and not 9475.

The input format is the first line will contain number of testcases and the first line of each testcase will contain the string.

We have to output the number extracted.

What I thought was to use `re` module  which will extract the numbers from the list and then sort it in descending order and then check whether the number is valid or not.

My Code:

```
import re
for _ in range(int(input())):
    a = input()
    pattern = '\d+'
    result = re.findall(pattern,a)
    result.sort(reverse = True)
    print(result)
```

But the output is very interesting.

Output:

```
1
This is alpha 5057 and 97
['97', '5057']
```

Why is the list not getting sorted in descending order?

Comment: you sort strings not integers... you could just use `result.sort(reverse=True, key=int)` if you wanted to sort by their numeric value.

Comment: It *did* sort in descending order.  '9' > '5'.  You fed it strings; you seem to expect a sort on the converted numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to convert the list values into `int`s first before you can do the sort:

```
import re
for _ in range(int(input())):
    a = input()
    pattern = '\d+'
    result = re.findall(pattern,a)
    result = map(int, result)
    result.sort(reverse = True)
    print(result)
```

See the python docs on [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and on the [sort function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort).